# How to use shortcuts on onscreen keyboard of an iPad?

Tags: keyboard, ipad

I have an iPad(iPadOS 17.1) and sadly keyboard commands are usually only available with an external keyboard, and neither is an external keyboard, nor the use of the often unpractical and slow context-menu aka the "apple-workflow" for many of my use-cases an acceptable condition. That being said, I want somehow a software onscreen-keyboard on the iPad capable of keyboard shortcuts as a hardware-keyboard.

What I have researched so far:

1. There are seemingly no 3rd party onscreen keyboards, that have cmd (command)-capabilities (Some 3rd party onscreen keyboards I've tested even had a cmd key in their layout, but this key was not bound to a cmd-functionality for keyboard-shortcuts and I found no options to change that.)
2. I also thought of using a remote control keyboard-app (such as "Air Keyboard"), but my attempts to host a local http-loopback server on the iPad and access it by this app failed (and the developer isn't responding to my questions I sent him regarding this) Thus I don’t know if a remote control of the iPad to itself "simulating" an external keyboard is feasible at all, but it might be…

So at this point I want to thank you in advance for your help.

Ps: jailbreaking of the iPad is not an option for me :)